# Get Concrete Class name from Abstract Class

Tags: java, abstract-class

In Java, inside an abstract class can I get the instance of the concrete class that extends it?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by calling [`this.getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--). This will give you the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance for the runtime type of `this`.

If you just want the name of the class, you could use [`this.getClass().getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--).

Lastly, there are also [`this.getClass().getSimpleName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--) and [`this.getClass().getCanonicalName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName--). I use the former all the time to print readable class names to log files and the like.

Comment: Here your example:  
`java.text.NumberFormat format = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance();`  
`System.out.println(format.getClass());`

Sorry, don't get the formatting to work...

@Peter: had some problems with newlines. posted too early...

Answer (score -2):

Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName()

Comment: Unwinding stack is extremely inefficient