# How to get a reference to the subclass inside an abstract java class

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, subclassing

All abstract classes in Java are obviously extended by a concrete class and cannot be instantiated on their own, how can I get a reference to the class that is extending my abstract class? My use case involves reflection and in my parent abstract class I want to introspect the methods on the concrete subclass and I can't figure out how to get a reference to the subclass without adding an abstract method forcing the subclass to return its Class. Any ideas?!

Comment: `this` will work, no?

Comment: I am not sure to understand. What is a subclass inside an abstract class ???  A abstract class has a superclass. It may also have subclasses. But the "inside" concept, I don't see. Sorry.

Comment: Say AbstractPerson is an abstract class in java and JohnSmith extends AbstractPerson, inside AbstractPerson can I get a reference to the JohnSmith subclass?

Comment: Again, what's wrong with simply using the `this` reference as mentioned in my first comment?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `this` as a reference to the current object. By calling `this.getClass()` inside your abstract class, you will get the Class instance for the subclass during runtime.

Additionally, your question was already answered here:

[Get Concrete Class name from Abstract Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901764/get-concrete-class-name-from-abstract-class)

Please, correct me, if I understood you wrong.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15340777)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, edited the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your abstract class doesn't "exist" at runtime, only concrete implementations can be instantiated.  Any method that is defined in the abstract superclass and is not overridden in the concrete class can reference "itself" through the `this` reference.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks!